# How can I send a file to the browser using Scalatra?

Tags: scalatra

I'm using the [scalatra-sbt-prototype](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype). What would I have to modify, and where , to be able to serve files from a directory on my filesystem? Say for example , I would want to serve the file `first.tar.gz` from `/home/downloads/first.tar.gz`, and have it accessible as:

```
http://localhost:8080/first.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `java.io.File` to the browser, from an action, seems to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

For correctness, you may also want to set the contentType so the browser doesn't try to display it as text/html if you have that set in your before filter and the disposition header with the correct name. Most browsers will infer the filename from the url but just to be sure, you can set it explicitly.

```
get("/first.tar.gz") {
    contentType = "application/octet-stream"
    val file = new java.io.File("/home/downloads/first.tar.gz")
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName)
    file
}
```

Obviously the route is very static but will do what you want.

Comment: I was thiking that maybe the handler will guess the mimetype?

Comment: @Geo Unfortunately it doesn't at the moment. Just tested with `curl --head`.